# How to add an image texture/color as an overlay to a base texture at a specific part of the object and animate the texture/color alpha?

Tags: animation, texturing

I have this image texture wrapped around a UV Sphere. I would like to add a separate color/image texture in the area inside red circle marked and animate the alpha of the newly added texture inside red circle. Is there any method to do this?

[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193519/how-to-add-image-texture-to-an-existing-material

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can use the same principle as this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193522/19156), and add a math node (or other) to control the decal the way you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the blend file. I tried the same method with Sphere but the results are strange. I cant get the mapping in the desired area.

Comment: Hi. How have you placed the empty? With snapping tools? Or could you show image of the result

Comment: Attaching blender file here. I added two image textures. In the mix RGB node I can only view one texture. Also when I use single image and try to map, its giving me a mirror like effect. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/EBEndqd5

Comment: @ArunNura, try this setting https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2LTR.jpg

Comment: The image is visible now, but its giving me a mirror like mapping: https://imgur.com/jpcSZGQ

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, move/scale/rotate the empty and eventually add some math nodes to avoid mirroring (i.e. Z > 0 only). I don't have your model, so hard to give setting that will exactly fit for you.

Comment: I meant don't have the textures (where not included in your file)

Comment: Could you please have a look on this blend file. I am not an expert in math nodes: hope this file will work https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Y0dWprkK

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=45DMNZyz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/45DMNZyz/) Adjusted empty scale/position/rotation and added some nodes in order to avoid the eye to be mirrored.

Comment: Oh Brilliant.!!!! Thanks alot man !!