# UV Simple question?

Tags: uv

Ok sorry very new.
So i have a question to ask.
All i want is to add a custom image to this part of the model.
We sell stickers so in effect i want the model to look like we stuck a sticker on it.
I am kind of struggling to figure out how to do this, i dont need to completely unwrap the selected part just kind of extract that section so that i can put my front number plate design on it.
Is there an easy way to do this, and sorry if it appears dumb.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an image texture/color as an overlay to a base texture at a specific part of the object and animate the texture/color alpha?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/how-to-add-an-image-texture-color-as-an-overlay-to-a-base-texture-at-a-specific)

Comment: If you removed all the unnecceray words that do not contribute to the communication like "Ok sorry very new. So i have a question to ask.", "kind of" and "and sorry if it appears dumb." the question would be easier and quicker to read. You should also give it a proper title reflecting your question. It's a question and answer site - everybody already knows it's going to be a question, you definitely do not need to tell us that, just ask it in the title next time and explain it in detail in the body of the question and you will get better answers sooner.

Comment: Just trying to be polite. WOW.

Comment: That doesnt answer entirely sorry. What i want to do is make a template from the plastic of the bike just of the section that will have the decal applied to it then unwrap only that face section so that i can design onto it and drop it into the model.

Comment: Hello :). You can simply select the faces you need and unwrap those. And then assign them a second material with your decal design :).

Comment: Hi that sounds like the go. However when i select the faces, they appear when i unwrap them but if i click anywhere else on the screen they all disapear?

Comment: Ah yes i have figured that out now and it works like a charm. Thank you so much,

Comment: Hey :). Glad to hear you figured it out. You can post a short answer, so others can learn from your solution