# uv map not working

Tags: uv

I am working on a powerpoint logo in blender.
[image: the project]

I want to add the P on the logo. I tried a refrence image but they dont show in the render. Now i am trying it with a uv map. i already unwrapped it and added the P but it is not showing. Can someone help me please?
[image: the uv map]

Comment: Probably the material setting does not consider the image. Can you upload your file **with textures included (packed)**. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Material settings (either from the property panel or shader editor).

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: can you please provide a picture. i cant find it

Comment: This kind of things (don't consider the animation part): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/how-to-add-an-image-texture-color-as-an-overlay-to-a-base-texture-at-a-specific/194800#194800