# One image for all objects

Tags: texturing, rigid-body-simulation

I created a wall with over 100 bricks. I want a logo on the wall. So some bricks will need a part of the logo. What's the fastest way?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far? Perhaps projected UV would work well.

Comment: honestly, nothing :)
But UV you have to edit every brick

Comment: yes, select all the cubes, choose a frontal view, go in Edit mode, unwrap with Project From View, move the faces in the UV Editor so that the Logo appears where you want it to appear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image texture to an existing material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193519/how-to-add-image-texture-to-an-existing-material)

Answer (score 10):

You can get there with UV projection.

1. Select all bricks and switch to Edit Mode
2. Get in front view (View > Viewpoint > Front)
3. Select all vertices and go *UV > Project from view*
4. Rearrange your UV map

[image]

---

> Useful hack:
> • Use a BW logo with black background
> • Set the image to clip (so it doesn't repeat)
> • Use MixRGB node to control the colors inside Blender

[image]

Comment: I think the point (certainly from the tags) is that the wall is made up of multiple bricks - not all one mesh - so that it can be run through a rigid body simulation. However, your solution does work just fine, providing you select all the separate bricks prior to the UV unwrap project from view.

Comment: @RichSedman You're right :). I forgot to separate the array when making the gifs. But it works the same way for 60 individual bricks :).

Comment: Updated the gif now, thanks again :).

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it with an empty as the *Object* of the *Texture Coordinate*:

- Give all your objects the same material.
- Create an empty in front of your cubes.
- Create a node setup with *Texture Coordinate (Object output socket) > Mapping > Image Texture (Clip mode) > MixRGB > Diffuse > Material Output*.
- Plug the *Image Texture Alpha* output into the factor of the *MixRGB*.
- In the *Texture Coordinate*, choose the empty as *Object*.
- Move and rotate the empty to place the image correctly on the faces.
- Give the other faces of your cubes another material if you don't want the image to be stretched.

[image]