# Prevent texture from scaling

Tags: texturing, scale

I've got a plane with its Base Color set to a texture (let it be 100x100 pixels). When I scale this plane the texture gets scaled too, which is not what I want.

How do I make Blender not to scale this texture no matter how big the plain is? I don't want it to be scaled beyond 100%.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Lemon's answer, if you scale your object in *Object* mode, you can't prevent the image to be scaled as well, but if you scale in *Edit* mode, you can keep the image texture at its current scale with the *Correct Face Attributes* option enabled (since 2.9):

[image]

Comment: It's strange, but I don't have this option.

Comment: Oh yes it's since 2.9

Answer (score 1):

Use *"object"* output from *"texture coordinates"* node:

[image]

Then to tune the texture position and scale, you can use the vector *"mapping"* node.

Also turn the image boundings to *"clip"* if you don't want it to repeat over the plane surface.

---

Alternatively, you can use another object as position, scale and rotation, [as indicated here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193519/how-to-add-image-texture-to-an-existing-material/193522#193522).

---

A link to [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#outputs).

> Object
>
> Uses an object as a source for coordinates. Often used with an empty,
> this is an easy way to place a small image at a given point on
> the object. This object can also be animated, to move a texture around
> or through a surface.