# How do I "flatten" my helmet's UV

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]I would like to make a magazine for a personal project that I want to apply later on my 3D helmet on blender.

I unwrap my UV (as on the screen) except that when I try to put a texture to try my text is curved etc.

I wanted to know if it was possible to simply have a "very large rectangle" of my helmet to be able to simply put my magazine (in A4 format for example) to put it on top and that everything is readable.

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe use a decal instead. For instance : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193522/19156

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/how-can-i-assign-an-image-texture-gradient-along-a-circlular-ring/